# Firebase Realtime Databae adds another layer of data

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

For some reason, my Firebase Realtime Database adds another layer when encoding my data. I am new to using Firebase services, so maybe I entered an incorrect link or smh. -N-1sGl-7VrhyIG7PdDa should not appear. I have a slight idea of why it's happening, but I don't know how to access that last part. Thanks in advance!

```
Future<void> AddUserGoals(
      String userId, String kcal, String p, String c, String f, BuildContext context) async {
    final url = Uri.parse(
        'https://recipier-e1139-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/usersData/$userId/userGoals.json');
    try {
      print(kcal);
      final response = await http.post(
        url,
        body: json.encode(
          {
            'currentBalance': kcal,
            'protein': p,
            'carbs': c,
            'fats': f,
          },
        ),
      );
      
      var decodedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
      print(decodedData['currentBalance']);
      if (decodedData['error'] == null) {
        balance = decodedData['currentBalance'];
      } else {
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (ctx) => const AlertDialog(
            title: Text('An error accured'),
            content: Text('Please try again later.'),
          ),
        );
      }
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (err) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }
 void didChangeDependencies() {
    if (_runsForFirstTime == true) {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = true;
      });
      User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
      Provider.of<RecipeProvider>(context).fetchProducts();
      Map<String, dynamic> initialData =
          ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map<String, dynamic>;
      Provider.of<DiaryProvider>(context, listen: false)
          .AddUserGoals(user!.uid, initialData['kcal']!, initialData['p']!,
              initialData['c']!, initialData['f']!, context)
          .then((_) {
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = false;
        });
      });
    }

    _runsForFirstTime = false;
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
```

[image: -N-1sGl-7VrhyIG7PdDa: this should not be here :)]

Comment: Not familiar with Flutter, but you seem to use `push` when writing to RTDB and `push` automatically generates a key for you - that's what you see there. Use `set` (or the equivalent for your platform) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `http.post()` you tell the REST server to create a new resource (with a unique ID) under the path, so that's what Firebase does.

If you want the server to write the data you pass at the path, use `http.put()`.

Also see:

- [What is the difference between POST and PUT in HTTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/what-is-the-difference-between-post-and-put-in-http)